# TextView : Null pointer Exception

Tags: java, android

I have a textview that its null in all fragment and MainActivity except onCreateDialog method.
so...i wanna use it in another method and i cant receive it because its null...
and seems that onCreateDialog method runs one time .
getView method returns a null value for call findViewById method.
what another way exist?
this is my code :

```
      public class AmanatDialog extends DialogFragment implements AmanatAdapter.OnDeleteBookAmanat { 
      private TextView centerTextAmanatDialog; 
       @NonNull
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext());
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.amanat , null , false);
    builder.setView(view);

   centerTextAmanatDialog = view.findViewById(R.id.center_text_amanat_dialog);


    recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.rv_amanat);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext() , RecyclerView.VERTICAL , false));
    recyclerView.setAdapter(amanatAdapter);
    EditText addBook = view.findViewById(R.id.et_amanat_addBook);
    MaterialButton btnSave = view.findViewById(R.id.btn_amanat_add_book);
    btnSave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            try {
                if(addBook.length() > 0){
                    onSendBookAmanatId.onSendBookId(Integer.parseInt(addBook.getText().toString()));
                    centerTextAmanatDialog.setText("");
                }
                else{
                    Toast.makeText(getContext() , "فیلد آیدی نمی تواند خالی باشد",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
    return builder.create();
}
```

what can i do?

this is my amanat layout

```
   <FrameLayout
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:orientation="vertical"
   android:padding="9dp">

    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/center_text_amanat_dialog"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="این کاربر هیچ کتابی امانت نگرفته است"
    android:fontFamily="@font/primary_regular"
    android:layout_gravity="center"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

and i want access of this method ...(this method is in AmanatDialog class in top)

```
    public void getBooksAmanat(Contact contact , ContacsDao contacsDao) throws 
    JSONException {

    
    this.contacsDao = contacsDao;
    this.contact = contact;
    String json = contacsDao.getBooksAmanat(contact.getId());
    if(json != null){
        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(json);
        List<Book> books = new ArrayList<>();
        for(int i = 0 ; i < jsonArray.length() ; i++){
            JSONObject jsonObject1 = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
            Book book = new Book();
            book.setId(jsonObject1.getInt("id"));
            book.setName(jsonObject1.getString("name"));
            book.setAuthor(jsonObject1.getString("author"));
            books.add(book);
        }


        amanatAdapter.setBooks(books);
        centerTextAmanatDialog.setText("");
    }
    else{
        centerTextAmanatDialog.setText("این کاربر هنوز کتابی امانت نگرفته است");
    }
}
```

Comment: Show amanat layout. What the exact error from logs?

Comment: So you want to access a textview in the dialog in an activity or fragment?

Comment: access to itself class(dialog)

Comment: i edited question...check now

Comment: Are you trying to set the text of centerTextAmanatDialog from getbooksAmanat?

Comment: yes...no matter , because it's null in all method

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to delete `view.` before the `findViewById`

try this

```
 centerTextAmanatDialog = findViewById(R.id.center_text_amanat_dialog);
```

Comment: i'm in dialog class ... i cant access without view